# MySQL CharacterSet Conversion of a column will impact the existing values or not

Tags: mysql, utf-8, latin1, mysql-5.1

```
I use MySQL 5.1 version
```

I have a MySQL table `'server_info'` which has 2 columns 'server_id' as well as 'server_details' of which the character set of `'server_details'` column was ***'latin1'*** and i have 100 rows of data in the table. Now, I got some error while updating the table with some specific string values. Error message follows

> 'Incorrect String value for column server_details....'

Which i realized that was due to the different character set.

So i decide to change my character to ***'utf-8'*** to support the new string as well.

- If i change the character set will the existing data affected?
- what will happen to the existing data?
- What all things i should be careful about before doing this
  conversion?
- Is this conversion, the right fix for my problem?

While i checked in `MySQL 5.6 version` The conversion gave me a messgage that '100 rows are affected' Does that mean existing data also got converted to the new character set?

- If Yes, Will this be the same behaviour i can expect in MySQL 5.1
  version also?

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` so we can see if the problem was during `INSERTion` or during `SELECTing`.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Character Set there will be no impact on the existing values. Because during the insertion the data lost ( or doesn't aware of) some extra information about the Character Set.
To fix this problem you have to convert the text manually.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer, try to be more descriptive